# Get 3 nodes from 2 NodeLists which have the biggest scores (an attribute that I have put myself)

Tags: javascript

I have two node lists, one of `<a>` elements and another one of `<img>` elements. The size of those node list is **different**.

I have added an attribute to each of those nodes called score. Right now I have a method that does this:

```
getImageWithBiggestScore: function(images,anchor_images) {

                var best_scored_image = images[0];

                for (var i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
                    if (images[i].score > best_scored_image.score) {
                        best_scored_image = images[i];
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < anchor_images.length; i++) {
                    if (anchor_images[i].score > best_scored_image.score) {
                        best_scored_image = anchor_images[i];
                    }
                }

                return best_scored_image;
            },
```

And this returns the node with the biggest score.  However, I would like to get the 3 nodes (or 5,6... Ideally it would be a parameter of the function) with the biggest scores. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got this right, you can do the following ...

**HTML**

```
<ul id='x'>
    <li data-score='1'></li>
    <li data-score='44'></li>
    <li data-score='2'></li>
    <li data-score='10'></li>
</ul>

<ul id='y'>
    <li data-score='9'></li>
    <li data-score='1'></li>
    <li data-score='1'></li>
    <li data-score='3'></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('x').children),   // images
    y = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('y').children),   // anchor_images
    z = [],             // array that will keep the results
    param = 4,          // number of nodes as a parameter
    sortFunc = function(a, b) { 
        if(typeof a === 'object' && typeof b === 'object') 
            return (b.getAttribute('data-score') * 1) - (a.getAttribute('data-score') * 1);
    }; // sort desc

x.sort(sortFunc);       // order the first array desc
y.sort(sortFunc);       // order the second array desc

// push into z the highest values of each array 
for(var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
    z.push(x[i]);
    z.push(y[i]);
}

// now, z contains the combination of the highest values from x and y
z.sort(sortFunc);   // sort desc the new array 
z = z.splice(0, param); // get the result :)

var result = "";

for(var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    result += z[i].getAttribute('data-score') + ",";
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

You may need to adapt to get this working with something specific to your code ...
The code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/YHjgY/5/

Comment: It's not an array of numbers... It's a nodelist https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList - where each node has an attribute called 'score'

Comment: Well, this was just an idea. I updated my code and the fiddle to work with nodeLists.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With a little bit of modifications, it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the recursion probably here

the recursion function would be something like this

```
var arrObjs = new Array();
arrObjs.push("a elements arr obj"); // pushes the complete array of a elements to the first index of arrObjs
arrObjs.push("div elements arr obj"); // 
var value = run(0,0);
function run (index,biggestScore){
    var arr = new Arrray();
    var smallestLength = 999; // could probably write this a better way. Assuming the length would not be more than 999 length
    for(var i=0; i < arrObjs.length;i++){
       if(arrObjs[i].length >= index){
          if((arrObjs[i].length-index) < smallestLength){
              smallestLength = arrObjs[i].length
          }
       arr.push(arrObjs[i]);
       }
    }

    for(var j=0; j < arr.length;j++){
       for(var k=index; k<arr[j].length;k++){
          if(arr[j][k].score>biggestScore){
              biggestScore.score = arr[j][k];
          }
       }
    }

    biggestScore = run(smallestLength,biggestScore);
    return biggestScore;
}
```

There could be a few errors. Didn't test it; I guess you understood the basic idea behind it. Let me know if you have any questions :)